# mariadb.service start stuck at activating

Tags: linux, mysql, database, mariadb, systemctl

I just installed the mariadb in my ubuntu 19.10 by `sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client` after when I am trying to start the server by `sudo systemctl start mariadb.service` shell get freeze I have to use `Ctl+c` to get shell running.
In the status it's showing **activating(start)**

- Other services are working fine with systemctl start

```
~$ sudo systemctl status mariadb.service  


mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.22 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2020-04-20 08:44:57 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 10705 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10707 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10711 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSRE
 Main PID: 10759 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 15 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 64.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─10759 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Apr 20 08:44:57 TheCybertron systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.22 database server...
Apr 20 08:44:57 TheCybertron mysqld[10759]: 2020-04-20  8:44:57 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 10759 ...
```

Comment: Check the log files of the service. It looks like the mysqld is in the process of a galera cluster recovery.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You probably had MySQL installed beforehand. This is a known bug: MySQL installs an AppArmor profile, and the MariaDB package fails to properly uninstall it (see details [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.1/+bug/1806263)).

You can use these commands to solve the problem (adapted from the bug mentioned above):

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" | sudo tee /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

This should display `Removal succeeded for "/usr/sbin/mysqld".`

Then, very important:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

Without this, some AppArmor profile comes back after reboot (not sure from where), preventing MariaDB from loading at all (unable to load libaio).

You can then start MariaDB with `sudo systemctl start mariadb`

Comment: This worked, but then I had to do another fix because /etc/mysql/debian-start was missing. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: I wish all answers would work as good as this one. Thanks!!!!

Comment: This worked and save me, so meaning the old mysql blocking the installation of mariadb